# flutter can't view on phone

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am new to flutter.

I am running flutter on Linux, with `flutter doctor` showing everything fine.

I set up a flutter project and set the SDK path to my `/flutter` full path.

When I go click on devices I get this:

[Android Studio Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TCaH.png)

If I pick Windows(Desktop) and run my flutter app, I can see the a window pop up for desktop and app running fine just like this:

[Example how web/desktop runs as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4GmO.png)

Yet when I pick `Pixel 3a API 34 extension level 7 x86 64(mobile)` I see no virtual mobile that  I can interact with the emulator and test the app. The logs are like this:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:42639/KkOnz6awBEk=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
```

How to solve this ? Do I need to add more mobile devices to that list, if so how ?

EDIT:

I realized I have no android images downloaded when I tried to Create A Device with Device Manager, just seen on the pic:

[Create New Device, No Android Image can be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtBJn.png)

So I started download now, could have this been the reason ?

Comment: do you have adb configured correctly? try using adb

Comment: I am very new to this, seem i can install adb tools with ```apt-get```, then do I need to run this inside android studio/flutter path to check on **virtual** devices ? most tutorials seem to connect to a real device via usb/wifi

Comment: i would suggest you to install android studio and import project in studio and launch emulator.

Comment: Check device manager & running devices tabs, you can find them in the top right corner